# Update From a Loop (Table Locking Issues + CLR Memory Issues)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, spatial

I have a table with a geography column.  I want to update this value, for a subset of rows (~1,000), based on the results of a query.

I have created a view that will return the geography column I want + the id of the row in the table to be updated.

If I run the query

```
UPDATE A
SET A.GeogCol = B.GeogCol
FROM TableToUpdate A
INNER JOIN UpdatedFrom_View B
ON A.ID = B.ID
```

I will receive a system out of memory error.  This occurs because it is 32 bit sql server and the VAS reservation runs out of space because of the CLR functions I call to create the geography column.  I am not the sever administrator, so I cannot temporarily allocate more space to the VAS reservation.

If I reduce this to `WHERE A.ID BETWEEN 0 AND 100` and attempt to manually itterate, I still have this problem sometimes.  I have found a few of the troublesome rows (larger geography objects than usual), and I can update those if I say WHERE `A.ID = @ID`.

My thought was then to update based on a loop.

```
DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @g GEOGRAPHY

DECLARE IDCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT ID FROM TableToUpdate
OPEN IDCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM IDCursor INTO @ID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SET @g = (SELECT GeogCol FROM UpdatedFrom_View WHERE ID = @ID)
  UPDATE TableToUpdate SET GeogCol = @g WHERE ID = @ID
  FETCH NEXT FROM IDCursor INTO @ID
END
CLOSE IDCursor
DEALLOCATE IDCursor
```

However this appears to have issues with table locking (I think).  It has now run for just under 2 days and has updated less than 150 records.

For reference, when done manually, `UPDATE TableToUpdate SET GeogCol = @g WHERE ID = @ID` takes less than 10 seconds.

Is there a better way to do this?

--EDIT

So I decided to test something.

I wrote this query which takes approximately 1 second.

```
UPDATE A
SET A.GeogCol = B.GeogCol
FROM TableToUpdate A
INNER JOIN UpdatedFrom_View B
ON  A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.ID BETWEEN 1 AND 1
```

Then I wrote a stored procedure that does the EXACT same thing.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestUpdate @IDLow INT, @IDHigh INT
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE A
  SET A.GeogCol = B.GeogCol
  FROM TableToUpdate A
  INNER JOIN UpdatedFrom_View B
  ON  A.ID = B.ID
  WHERE A.ID BETWEEN @IDLow AND @IDHigh
END

GO

EXEC TestUpdate @IDLow = 1, @IDHigh = 1
```

This query takes over half an hour.  What is happening?

Comment: How many rows are you updating here? I suspect the problem is in UpdateFrom_View. What is that view?

Comment: @SeanLange what do you mean when you say "the problem."  I am updating about 1,100 rows.  The view consists of doing a whole bunch of sql spatial functions to create some lines and then applying a UnionAggregate function to turn them into one record.  It works fine and does not reference the table to be updated, but it relies almost entirely on CLR functions.

Comment: The memory issue is most likely from the CLR functions. Those can get rather memory hungry sometimes, especially with spatial functions. Strange that is has been running for 2 days and only updated 150 rows. Is there something in the CLR that isn't releasing objects possibly?

Comment: @SeanLange.  Yes, the memory issue is definitely from the CLR.  I have been aware of this problem for a while now.  Are you suggesting that if I ran a query to update a non-CLR column like an INT from a loop that it would not take this long?

Comment: With only 1,100 rows an update from like you posted would normally take so little time you would barely notice it happened. A cursor will add some overhead as it has to do it row by row but with only 1,100 rows it would still be lightning fast.

Comment: @SeanLange, I posted an edit.  Do you have any idea what I am seeing?

Comment: As a guess it sounds like it very likely you are seeing a case of parameter sniffing here. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2007/11/27/parameter-sniffing/